# Can you email different sections to different people from one form created in infopath and submitted to sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, infopath, infopath-2007

So for example I have 3 sections, and each person has a complaint box (regular text box) and a person responsible (contact selector).  Now when I submit the form, how do I get each sections to email the person specified by the person responsible?

I am using Infopath 2007 along with Sharepoint 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the texboxes are promoted to SharePoint list columns.
2. Create a workflow in SharePoint Designer.
3. Set the workflow to run automatically when item is added
4. Add three Send Email actions to the workflow, each going to a different recipient and each containing data from a different column